# How may I flatten this multiple arrays into 1?

Tags: php

This is the representation of my array from the view of var_dump and print_r :

I need to use array_unique but it doesn't work for this array so i was thinking that if i could flatten it to all fit one array then the unique will work.

**var_dump :**

```
{
  ["Source"]=>
  string(12) "10.96.250.49"
}
array(1) {
  ["Source"]=>
  string(12) "10.96.250.49"
}
array(1) {
  ["Source"]=>
  string(12) "10.96.250.49"
}
```

**print_r :**

```
Array
(
    [Source] => 10.96.250.49
)
Array
(
    [Source] => 10.96.250.49
)
Array
(
    [Source] => 10.96.250.49
)
```

Comment: Will the values always be the same, if so why not just always pull the first array. $array[0];

Comment: @DavidJones sadly won't always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.5+, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) to extract all the `Source` values:

```
$result = array_unique(array_column($array, 'Source'));
```

If  you're using an older PHP version, simply loop through your array and create a flattened array, like so:

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $subarr) {
    $new[] = $subarr['Source'];
}

$result = array_unique($new);
```

Comment: I am using php5. Here is the result `array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}
array(0) {
}`

Comment: @LearningPHP: I'm not sure what your original array contains, then. Can you post an example at eval.in?

Comment: The data are IPs gotten from the database using `while($ips = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))$arr = $ips}`

Comment: I don't know how your array looks like, @LearningPHP. Without that I can only suggest a generic solution. If you're having troubles getting it to work, then please post the output of the folowing statement. (make sure you put it ***after*** your loop): `echo '<pre>'.print_r($YOUR_ARRAY_HERE, TRUE).'</pre>';`