# global $wpdb displaying garbage data along with results of my select query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

I have a custom table in MySQL database, which I am trying to query using `global $wpdb`. I have defined my query using information available from the following two sources:

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
2. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233021/display-data-on-word-press-site-posts-and-pages-from-mysql-table

This is how the data is in **phpMyAdmin**:

[image: data in phpMyAdmin]

The query seems to be working fine as it selects data from my custom table, however the output seems to contain garbage/unnecessary information apart from the information that is available in the table.

I want it to display as a table/similar to how it is displayed in **phpMyAdmin**, where I am able to associate the **SrNo**, **Compound** etc with other columns in the table:

```
add_shortcode('wpse_233031_shortcode', function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM PNaphtha");
    //$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM PNaphtha" );
    ob_start();
    echo var_dump($myrows );
    //return ob_get_clean(); 
});
```

I get the following results

[image]

```
array(10) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#6275 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["Compound"]=> string(12) "abietic acid"
    }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#6274 (2) { 
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "3"
        ["Compound"]=> string(12) "acenaphthene"
    }
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#6273 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "4"
        ["Compound"]=> string(6) "acetal"
    }
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#6272 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "5"
        ["Compound"]=> string(12) "acetaldehyde"
    }
    [4]=> object(stdClass)#6271 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "6"
        ["Compound"]=> string(9) "acetamide"
    }
    [5]=> object(stdClass)#6270 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "7"
        ["Compound"]=> string(11) "acetanilide"
    }
    [6]=> object(stdClass)#6269 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "8"
        ["Compound"]=> string(11) "acetic acid"
    }
    [7]=> object(stdClass)#6268 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(1) "9"
        ["Compound"]=> string(16) "acetic anhydride"
    }
    [8]=> object(stdClass)#6267 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(2) "10"
        ["Compound"]=> string(7) "acetone"
    }
    [9]=> object(stdClass)#6266 (2) {
        ["SrNo"]=> string(2) "11"
        ["Compound"]=> string(19) "acetone cyanohydrin"
    }
}
```

Although, all of the information I queried is available here, there is also a lot of unnecessary information.

I tried the following changes, however none of them seems to be working

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM PNaphtha"); // get_row

output_type changed to ARRAY_A, ARRAY_N, OBJECT_K

echo var_dump changed to echo array
```

I will appreciate if you could please advise on how to get the results to format as a table or array. Also, I have placed the above code in the `functions.php` file of my theme. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have serialized data in one of your fields?

Comment: What's garbage about that? It's just how PHP shows nested data and objects.

Comment: Thank you for your response. No, I don't have serialized data. I added a screenshot of the data as it appears in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: That code belongs in your functions.php (unless you made a plugin), so it's good there. Did you try `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $myrows, TRUE ) . '</pre>;`?

Comment: Thanks disinfor. What you suggested makes a difference, it displays the results a little "neatly" as in new lines, giving it sort of bullet like feel however the "garbage" is still in there.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SrNo] => 2
            [Compound] => abietic acid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SrNo] => 3
            [Compound] => acenaphthene
        )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're getting object as output, that's why you're seeing that information in there. Make the following change. Add 'ARRAY_A' (associative array) to the end of your function call.

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM PNaphtha", ARRAY_A);
```

That will keep your query from being returned as an object and your `var_dump` will look the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you Difster, I had already tried ARRAY_A and ARRAY_N, however I still get "garbage" data.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [SrNo] => 2 [Compound] => abietic acid ) [1] => Array ( [SrNo] => 3 [Compound] => acenaphthene ) [2] => Array ( [SrNo] => 4 [Compound] => acetal ) [3] => Array ( [SrNo] => 5 [Compound] => acetaldehyde ) [4] => Array ( [SrNo] => 6 [Compound] => acetamide ) [5] => Array ( [SrNo] => 7 [Compound] => acetanilide ) [6] => Array ( [SrNo] => 8 [Compound] => acetic acid ) [7] => Array ( [SrNo] => 9 [Compound] => acetic anhydride ) [8] => Array ( [SrNo] => 10 [Compound] => acetone ) [9] => Array ( [SrNo] => 11 [Compound] => acetone cyanohydrin ) ) 1

Comment: well, that looks like it should. What you're seeing there is the array indexes. Even if you specify Associative, it still has numeric indexes also. This is completely predictable and normal behavior. It looks exactly how I expect it to. Now you just need to  loop through your array.

Comment: Can you please advise what looping through the array means.

Comment: Tell me what your'e trying to do with the data and I'll help you figure it out. There are any number of ways to manipulate the data.

Comment: Difster, I am trying to display the data as a "table" on my page. So, when I SELECT * FROM `PNaphtha` I want the table to display similar to how it shows in phpMyAdmin. I will of course limit the columns and rows to make it more manageable.

Comment: I made an example of how you would make a complete table using just 2 of your columns. You can probably figure out the rest from there.
Please mark this as solved if that fixes your problem.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a4f2b13df353188f5be375a15b26c9fca27c324

Comment: Difster, I am currently traveling and do not have access to my laptop. I really appreciate your comment.  I will test your solution in 1-2 days and mark this as solved.

Comment: Hi Difster, based on your advise I used 

    add_shortcode('wpse_233031_shortcode', function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM 
    PNaphtha", ARRAY_A);

    echo "<table><tr><th>SrNo></th><th>Compound</th></tr>";

    foreach($results as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['SrNo'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Compound'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<table>";

However, I get... This page isn’t working www.xxxxx.xxx is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Based on your suggestion about looping through the array, I also checked the following (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074720/how-may-i-flatten-this-multiple-arrays-into-1/22074780#22074780), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528481/how-to-loop-through-array-of-multiple-arrays-in-php) and a few more but I get the same HTTP ERROR 500 on all of my pages. I think I may be missing something fundamental.

Comment: `foreach ( $myrows as $row) {
    echo $row[ 'SrNo' ] ." ". $row[ 'Compound']. " ". $row['Tc (K)']." ". $row['Pc (bar)']." ";
}` kind of produces reasonable results, however I want to format it as a table which so far I have been unsuccessful. I used a where clause to limit to one row and I get 

2 abietic acid 832.000 16.800


Thank you for guiding me in the right direction. I will mark your answer as accepted, however if you could please also help in formatting it as a table with column header I will appreciate it.

Comment: I removed echo "<table>"; from your original code, and voila I have a beautiful table with all the columns and the values. The tables seems to have appeared below the footer itself but that is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you are using var_dump

The `var_dump` function displays structured information about variables/expressions including its type and value.

I would recommend using print_r

The print_r() displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans. array values will be presented in a format that shows keys and elements.

You should be able to see a change if you change

```
var_dump($myrows )
```

to

```
print_r($myrows)
```

**Here's how I did what you are wanting (Without echoing the result):**

```
$sql = "SELECT `Srno`,`compound` FROM `pnaphtha`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['Srno']."</td><td>".$row['compound']."</td></tr>";
    }

 echo "</table>";
```

However since you are using WordPress I would suspect it would be something along the lines of

```
global $wpdb;
$sql =  "SELECT `SrNo`, `Compound` FROM PNaphtha";
//you may need to add ARRAY_A

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

echo "<table>";
while($myrows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$myrows['SrNo']."</td><td>".$myrows['Compound']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I can't actually test the wordpress version as I can't be bothered to set up a wordpress install haha

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried changing to print_r($myrows) but now all it displays is Array ( ) 1.

Comment: I am sorry Elliot, I had some part of my code commented while I tested your suggestion. print_r seems to help, but I still get Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => abietic acid ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => acenaphthene ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => acetal ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => acetaldehyde ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => acetamide ) [5] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => acetanilide ) [6] => Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => acetic acid ) [7] => Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => acetic anhydride ) [8] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => acetone ) [9] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => acetone cyanohydrin ) ) 1

Comment: You could try var_export()?

Comment: It seems to have deleted the square brackets. array ( 0 => array ( 'SrNo' => '2', 'Compound' => 'abietic acid', ), 1 => array ( 'SrNo' => '3', 'Compound' => 'acenaphthene', ), 2 => array ( 'SrNo' => '4', 'Compound' => 'acetal', ), 3 => array ( 'SrNo' => '5', 'Compound' => 'acetaldehyde', ), 4 => array ( 'SrNo' => '6', 'Compound' => 'acetamide', )......

Comment: I really appreciate your help, however this one does not work at all. I am vaguely familiar with WordPress and not at all familiar with the "classical" way of doing this, so I am not able to tell what may have gone wrong. However, I get the general HTTP error upon adding your code to the functions.php file. This page isn’t working www.xxxxxx.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Did add the wordpress version of it ? or the original?

Comment: The WordPress version.